# Check if file copy was successful

Tags: php, file, copy

After running the command `copy($uploadedFile, "pdf/".$fullFileName);`, what would be the **quickest** and **most efficient** way to verify that the file copied successfully?

Comment: `copy()` returns false on failure, so `if (copy(...)) { //success } else {//failure}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be enough no?

```
if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [copy function in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php), you'll see:

```
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.
```

So, something as simple as:

```
if(!copy($uploadedFile, "pdf/".$fullFileName)) {
    // Failure code
}
```

Or:

```
$returnCode = copy($uploadedFile, "pdf/".$fullFileName);
if(!$returnCode) {
    // Failure code
}
```

would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare size whlist copying - if sizes equals we can assume copying is done..

```
$fs1=$fs='';

$filename = 'test.zip'; // copy from ftp or slow copy..

  if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();

  for ($i = 0; $i<25; $i++){

          echo "<hr> Compare \n";
          echo "<br>fs1: $fs1";

          $fs='';
          $fs = filesize($filename);
          echo "<br>fs: $fs";
          if ( $i > 0 )
              if (  $fs1 === $fs ) break;

          $fs1 = $fs;

          ob_flush();
          flush();
          sleep(2);
          clearstatcache();
  }

  echo "<br>Done copying.";
  ob_end_flush();
```